# Importing psycopg2 in Heroku with Python and Node.js

Tags: python, node.js, heroku

So, I'm trying to import psycopg2 to communicate with an SQL database in Python, for an app hosted on Heroku. I've read all the manuals saying "just put it in your requirements.txt" and I've tried that. Problem is, the app is primarily Node.js, and the app only calls Python. I don't think Heroku is even looking for a requirements.txt in this case. I've also tried putting a folder for the module in my root directory, but that's not working either. I have the Python script setup to log to the console in a browser through a client side script and all, so I can see the output. I keep getting an `ImportError: no module named psycopg2`.

How am I supposed to import a 3rd party module here?

Some code in Node.js:

```
app.get('/my_route', (req, res) => {
    var process = spawn('python', ["python_script.py", "MSG:Hi there!"]);
    process.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        res.send(data);
    });
});
```

This just routes every request to www.my_website.com/my_route to python_script.py with the argument "MSG:Hi there!". In my Python script, it checks the first 3 letters of the argument against a list of codes, and sends the rest of the argument to a specific function. In Python:

```
try:
    import psycopg2
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Whatever it prints goes back to Node as the `data` variable, and then gets send to whoever made the request. In this case, I have an HTML script sending requests to this URL and logging the output to the console. It's all complex and confusing but basically it goes like this:

client side HTML asks for output by sending a request to a certain URL
server side Node.js receives the request and sends it on to Python
Python does the SQL management amongst other things (but it can't import psycopg2)
Node.js receives the output from Python (in this case an error message)
client side HTML receives what Node.js sent along and logs it to the console.

Comment: have you added the psycopg2 package name in requiremnet.txt file

Comment: Yes, as I said in the original post, I did. It didn't work, presumably because it is a node.js app with Python in it, instead of a solely Python app. I think Heroku isn't even looking for a requirements.txt file for that reason.

Comment: can you also share the requirment.txt file in question

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit as to what you mean by "a node.js app with Python in it"? Adding some code to your question would help us to see how you have them working together.

Comment: Sure, I'll add some code. Basically its just Node.js spawning a Python child process, and Express returning the output.